# "Insert Hyperlink" very slow for documents in a SharePoint library

Tags: microsoft-word, sharepoint, webdav

I'm working in a Word 2010 document from a SharePoint document library. When you use the "Insert Hyperlink" command (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) to add a hyperlink to text in the document, by default, the Insert Hyperlink dialog opens onto the directory where your file is saved. Because my document is stored in SharePoint, this means that the dialog must connect to the WebDAV folder where the document is stored, an operation that can take between 10 and 30 seconds every time I open the dialog. I have to insert hundreds of links into this document, so these delays are unworkable.

Is there a way to make Word use a different directory as the current folder in the Insert Hyperlink dialog so I don't have to go through this? Alternately, is there a good way to avoid the dialog entirely when adding hyperlinks? All my links are Web URLs, so I never even need access to the local file system anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you browse another folder once and click *OK*, this is saved for next time.

But if you want to link to WebDAV documents again, next time you return to create a link, you will have this problem again.

Comment: @hlhck thanks for your edit cause my language is Persian and i'm beginner

Comment: absolutely if your SharePoint server has visitors with normal load , you have better speed to open them with explorer compared with Server that haven't any visitors unlike which we expected. beacause when server reserve resources to use sharepoint application in application start session is better performance compared with when application session being closed (has delay to start and then  reserve and then prepare and etc.)

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: what is your version of windows and office and sharepoint server?

Comment: Office 2010, Windows 7, SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer, go to the Gear icon to Internet Options, to Connections to LAN Settings and make sure the box to auto detect proxy settings is not checked.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the answer. Save and reboot. Works like a charm every time. What a relief!!!

Comment: Please don't post a thank you comment as an answer. It will be deleted. Read [about] and [ask] if you want to know how this site works.